# XSS Protection for C# not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xss

Hi I have a text box without validation when I am trying to put value like `<script>alert(1)</script>` and proceed with submit it is showing alert I wan to restrict this.

I already used in webconfig:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

but it is not working, I cant use js escape validation as it is all over my application and doing manually to each cshtml is quite impossible. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Not the answer you were searching for (probably) but it's possible to pass that value with the `[AllowHTML]` annotation.

Comment: What do you mean by JS escape validation?

Comment: @Erlend escape validation like making regex to skip the alert and all